# How to set using magic setter child array of Observer object

Tags: event-observer, object, magic-getter

My observer $observer has the basic format:

```
$observer->_data['result']->_data['booked'][productid][date]
```

I can access this value like:

```
$observer->getResult()->getBooked($productid)['2014-10-30 08:00']
```

But I cannot set it. Is there someway in Magento set set children arrays (multi-dimensional)? I have searched but can't find how to do this. I need something like:

```
$observer->getResult()->setBooked(($productid)['2014-10-30 08:00'], $value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I have all the facts. but give this a try:

```
$result = $observer->getResult()
$booked = $result->getBooked();
$booked[product id here][date here] = $value;
$result->setBooked($booked);
```

If `$observer->getResult()` is an object (ant it looks like it is) it will be passed by reference, so any modifications you make to it will be taken into account in other scripts that use it.
So the idea of my code is to get the `booked` data from the result object, modify it and attach the modified value to the result again.